# Put new mapping with elasticsearch-ruby

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I want to [put a new mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/indices-put-mapping.html#indices-put-mapping) to a index without deleting the index. [`Elasticsearch::Model`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-model/Elasticsearch/Model/) does not seem to provide an API for this. Or do I miss it?

Answer (score 1):

**1 Login to your elastic search client**

```
require 'elasticsearch'
client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
```

**2 Create new index with mapping data**

```
client.indices.create index: 'testindex', body: {
   "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "properties": {
      title: { type: 'text' }
    }
  }
}
```

**3 checked your newly created index**

```
client.indices.get_mapping index: "testindex"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can PUT a new mapping over the old mapping without deleting any data or dropping the index.  The catch is that updated field mappings only get applied to new data, not existing data.  If you want the new mapping to be applied to old data then you need to re-index.

Comment: Indeed. I would have to reindex everything. My question was about how to change the mapping using the elasticsearch-ruby API.

Answer (score 0):

Given the Elasticsearch client, you can update the existing field mappings like this:

```
client.indices.put_mapping index: 'myindex', type: 'mytype', body: {
  mytype: {
    properties: {
      title: { type: 'string', analyzer: 'snowball' }
    }
  }
}
```

See https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/master/elasticsearch-api/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/indices/put_mapping.rb#L50